# LibGDX how to make scene2D notification label scroll inside container

Tags: java, user-interface, scroll, libgdx, scene2d

I am making a small game with LibGDX, and for this game I need a small container, which is a scene2D Stack, and inside that container is a label.

My problem is, that this label may only be on one line, and if the label text is longer than the container width, then it has to slowly move/scroll from right to the left, so the player can see the entire notification text. and when all the text has been shown, then the sliding should start over.

The best example I can come up with, for the behavior, is a digital text sign like in the image below

Hope anyone has some guides or can show me some code, to get me going :)

[image: Digital Text Sign]

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd create a table (label container) and a label(text) and change the position of the label accordingly and then reset it. Respecting all of the label.getwidth and so on

Comment: But how do I hide some of the label text, when it scrolls out of the container scope?

Comment: Like I said on facebook, use a Window to keep the outer text hidden, but for future people that stumble upon this, just use a window :3 peace